# In a Docker Compose multi-container application, how to prevent Postgres from running statements previously issued

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm running a [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) project with an Item Pipeline which writes data to a PostgreSQL database. It is a [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) multi-container application with the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  privoxy:
    build: ./privoxy
    links:
      - tor

  tor:
    build:
      context: ./tor
      args:
        password: "foo"

  scraper:
    build: ./scraper
    environment:
      - http_proxy=http://privoxy:8118
      - PGPASSWORD=iperpassword
    links:
      - tor
      - privoxy
      - db
    volumes:
      - scraper-data:/scraper/apkmirror_scraper/data
      - scraper-jobdir:/scraper/apkmirror_scraper/crawls

  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=iperpassword
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  scraper-data:
  scraper-jobdir:
  db-data:
```

I'm using the `postgres` image from the official repository (https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/), and have made the `/var/lib/postgresql/data` directory into a volume following https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference.

The problem is that when I start the application, the `db` service outputs logs and errors pertaining to things I tried previously, not what I'm trying to do now. This is what I see:

```
apkmirrorscrapercompose_tor_1 is up-to-date
apkmirrorscrapercompose_db_1 is up-to-date
apkmirrorscrapercompose_privoxy_1 is up-to-date
Recreating apkmirrorscrapercompose_scraper_1
Attaching to apkmirrorscrapercompose_tor_1, apkmirrorscrapercompose_db_1, apkmirrorscrapercompose_privoxy_1, apkmirrorscrapercompose_scraper_1
scraper_1  |                                  List of databases
scraper_1  |    Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |  Collate   |   Ctype    |   Access privileges   
scraper_1  | -----------+----------+----------+------------+------------+-----------------------
scraper_1  |  postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | 
scraper_1  |  template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres          +
scraper_1  |            |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
scraper_1  |  template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres          +
scraper_1  |            |          |          |            |            | postgres=CTc/postgres
scraper_1  | (3 rows)
scraper_1  | 
scraper_1  | Postgres is up - executing command
scraper_1  | Tor appears to be working. Proceeding with command...
scraper_1  | 2017-06-30 12:32:59 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.4.0 started (bot: apkmirror_scraper)
scraper_1  | 2017-06-30 12:32:59 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'apkmirror_scraper', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'apkmirror_scraper.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['apkmirror_scraper.spiders']}
scraper_1  | 2017-06-30 12:32:59 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
scraper_1  | ['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
scraper_1  |  'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
scraper_1  |  'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
scraper_1  |  'scrapy.extensions.closespider.CloseSpider',
scraper_1  |  'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
db_1       | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
db_1       | This user must also own the server process.
db_1       | 
db_1       | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
db_1       | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
db_1       | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
db_1       | 
db_1       | Data page checksums are disabled.
db_1       | 
db_1       | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
db_1       | creating subdirectories ... ok
db_1       | selecting default max_connections ... 100
db_1       | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
db_1       | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
db_1       | creating configuration files ... ok
db_1       | running bootstrap script ... ok
db_1       | performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
db_1       | 
db_1       | WARNING: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
db_1       | You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
db_1       | --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
db_1       | syncing data to disk ... ok
db_1       | 
db_1       | Success. You can now start the database server using:
db_1       | 
db_1       |     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
db_1       | 
db_1       | waiting for server to start....LOG:  database system was shut down at 2017-06-29 13:40:40 UTC
db_1       | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
db_1       | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
db_1       | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
db_1       |  done
db_1       | server started
db_1       | ALTER ROLE
db_1       | 
db_1       | 
db_1       | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
db_1       | 
db_1       | LOG:  received fast shutdown request
db_1       | waiting for server to shut down....LOG:  aborting any active transactions
db_1       | LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
db_1       | LOG:  shutting down
db_1       | LOG:  database system is shut down
db_1       |  done
db_1       | server stopped
db_1       | 
db_1       | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
db_1       | 
db_1       | LOG:  database system was shut down at 2017-06-29 13:40:41 UTC
db_1       | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
db_1       | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
db_1       | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
db_1       | LOG:  received smart shutdown request
db_1       | LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
db_1       | LOG:  shutting down
db_1       | LOG:  database system is shut down
db_1       | LOG:  database system was shut down at 2017-06-29 13:41:53 UTC
db_1       | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
db_1       | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
db_1       | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
db_1       | LOG:  received smart shutdown request
db_1       | LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
db_1       | LOG:  shutting down
db_1       | LOG:  database system is shut down
db_1       | LOG:  database system was shut down at 2017-06-29 13:43:22 UTC
db_1       | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
db_1       | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
db_1       | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
db_1       | LOG:  received smart shutdown request
db_1       | LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
db_1       | LOG:  shutting down
db_1       | LOG:  database system is shut down
db_1       | LOG:  database system was shut down at 2017-06-29 13:52:02 UTC
db_1       | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
db_1       | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
db_1       | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
db_1       | ERROR:  column "developer" of relation "apks" does not exist at character 31
db_1       | STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO apks (url, title, developer, app, version_name, version_code, architectures, package, apk_file_size, android_min_version, android_target_version, supported_dpis, md5_signature, time_uploaded, time_scraped, image_urls, images, file_urls, files, created_on, updated_on) VALUES ('http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/sony-mobile-communications/backup-restore-unknown-developer/backup-restore-unknown-developer-1-2-a-1-23-release/backup-restore-1-2-a-1-23-android-apk-download/', 'Backup & restore 1.2.A.1.23', 'Sony Mobile Communications', 'Backup & restore', '1.2.A.1.23', '2360343', ARRAY['arm'], 'com.sonymobile.synchub', 9541452, '6.0', '7.1', ARRAY['nodpi'], 'eda39fedfc33ea939a5bb4926b3980c1', '2017-04-25T16:30:00+00:00'::timestamptz, '2017-06-29T14:10:39+00:00'::timestamptz, ARRAY['http://www.apkmirror.com/wp-content/themes/APKMirror/ap_resize/ap_resize.php?src=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.apkmirror.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2017%2F04%2F58ff36aea8e0c.png&w=96&h=96&q=100'], '{}', ARRAY['http://www.apkmirror.com/wp-content/themes/APKMirror/download.php?id=203068'], '{}', '2017-06-29T14:19:21.661193'::timestamp, '2017-06-29T14:19:21.661207'::timestamp) RETURNING apks.id
db_1       | LOG:  received smart shutdown request
db_1       | LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
db_1       | LOG:  shutting down
db_1       | LOG:  database system is shut down
db_1       | LOG:  database system was shut down at 2017-06-29 16:28:54 UTC
db_1       | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
```

Although I'm not showing details on the application, my main point is that I'm positive that data shown in the error message is from a previous run, and not from the APK download page that I'm currently trying to scrape.

In short, it seems like PostgreSQL is 'caching' previous statements and trying to re-run them even after I stop the application, do `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up`. It seems to me that this behavior must somehow be driven by the data in `/var/lib/postgresql/data`, since this volume is the only thing that is persisted across restarting the container.

Is this indeed the case? If so, how can I disable this 'statement caching' behavior?

Comment: What do you mean with _things tried previously_? Some of the postgres logs could depend on operations run from the entrypoint files. I would check what happens by only running `docker-compose up -d --no-deps db`, this command eventually interrupting other container connections.

Comment: [steppo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/917617/steppo), by 'things tried previously' I mean that I was at first running a different Python script (actually a Scrapy crawl command) at the `CMD` of the `Dockerfile` of the `scraper`; that why I 'recognize' these error messages although I wouldn't expect them now. I had a look at `postgres`' entrypoint script, https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/master/9.6/docker-entrypoint.sh, but I couldn't see any code which explains this 'statement caching' behavior?

Comment: Are you sure you've deleted your 'persistent' volumes too when you tried to restart your docker-compose environment?

Comment: [lorenzvth7](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4525448/lorenzvth7), actually I'm sure I didn't delete the volumes. If I delete them using `docker rm -v $(docker ps -aq)` and `docker volume rm $(docker volume -q)`, the 'old' error messages go away. However, I would prefer for only those old statements to disappear and not all the data in `/var/lib/postgresql/data`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This just means that docker-compose is re-starting your previously stopped container (or re-attaching to it, if it is already running), and because of there is no need to re-build the image:

```
apkmirrorscrapercompose_db_1 is up-to-date
```

So, what your are seeing "again" in the logs is the `docker logs` of that container which includes all the life-generated logs of postgres.

Simply remove the container and start again (the db data is persisted in the volume, so it will survive):

```
docker-compose rm db
```